# Attribute Error for Axisbg in Python

Tags: python

Got "Attribute Error: Unknown property axisbg" in python, Please give me a suggestion to solve this?

here is my code:

```
 import matplotlib

 import matplotlib.pyplot as hit

 kit = hit.figure()

 pot = kit.patch

 pot.set_facecolor('green') 

 x = [3,12,20,24,29]

 y = [5,9,15,19,23]

 bit = kit.add_subplot(1,1,1,axisbg='red')
```

Comment: i think that the field "axisbg" does not exist, have a look at https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html

Answer (score 0):

API Changes in 2.0.0
Deprecation and removal
Color of Axes

The axisbg and axis_bgcolor properties on Axes have been deprecated in favor of facecolor.